# Pyqrt5 Python Need delete zero on display

Tags: python, functional-buttons

Прошу помочь удалить 0 при нажатии на кнопку. Когда создавал дизайн калькулятора в label_2 как текст написал "0". И при запуски калькулятора на дисплее появляется 0... после нажатии на кнопки выводит: 05665 и тд.

```
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda:self.after_clicked(num=0))
    self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.after_clicked(num=1))
    self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.after_clicked(num=2))
    self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.after_clicked(num=3))

def after_clicked(self, num):
    self.label_2.setText(self.label_2.text() + str(num))
```

Comment: Переведите заголовок на русский язык + метки -- в метки, а не в заголовок

Comment: я же вам ответил в предыдущем ответе, что не так?